# PHP - dom appendChild() - adding strings around selected html tags using PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom, append

I'm trying to run through some html and insert some custom tags around every instance of an "A" tag. I've got so far, but the last step of actually appending my pseudotags to the link tags is eluding me, can anyone offer some guidance?

It all works great up until the last line of code - which is where I'm stuck. How do I place these pseudotags either side of the selected "A" tag?

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($section);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$ahrefs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($ahrefs as $ahref) {
    $valueID = $ahref->getAttribute('name');
    $pseudostart = $dom->createTextNode('%%' . $valueID . '%%');
    $pseudoend = $dom->createTextNode('%%/' . $valueID . '%%');
    $ahref->parentNode->insertBefore($pseudostart, $ahref);
    $ahref->parentNode->appendChild($pseudoend);
    $expression[] = $valueID; //^$link_name[0-9a-z_()]{0,3}$
    $dom->saveHTML();
}
//$dom->saveHTML();
```

I'm hoping to get this to perform the following:

```
<a href="xxx" name="yyy">text</a>
```

turned into

```
%%yyy%%<a href="xxx" name="yyy">text</a>%%/yyy%%
```

But currently it doesn't appear to do anything - the page outputs, but there are no replacements or nodes added to the source.

Comment: Did you try my edited suggestion?

Comment: Hiya yeah just tried that - same error as before!

Comment: OK updated the above completely to reflect the new situation - I really need to get this working, I can't see another way of doing it :)

Comment: You forgot to `$pseudostart = $dom->createTextNode('%%' . $valueID . '%%');` etc.

Comment: Hiya, sorry edited the wrong code in - I've got this running and it does output a page, but it's not actually appended anything - the source is completely free of %%%% etc.

Comment: How do you dump the DOM-tree back into a string? `$dom->saveXML()`?

Comment: Hiya, yeah - tried that, both inside and outside of the loop. No effect as yet. Still trying to learn about these commands. One thought I had was that there might not be a parent, as this is HTML not XML and so the parent is effectively the surrounding <body> tag?

Comment: The save command should definitely go outside of the loop. You might need to post a snippet of your HTML. I will update my answer below.

Comment: Your parser works fine, I've tried it out and it outputs what you wanted. You could try creating a new file and make some tests there to see if there are some changes and if you get what you want. Let us know.

Comment: Jensgram - that worked! Thank you so much, that's been such a headache for me!

Comment: @hfidgen: Great. In that case I'll edit my answer to reflect to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sure that the `ahref` node is wrapped...

```
foreach($ahrefs as $ahref) {
    $valueID = $ahref->getAttribute('name');
    $pseudostart = $dom->createTextNode('%%' . $valueID . '%%');
    $pseudoend = $dom->createTextNode('%%/' . $valueID . '%%');
    $ahref->parentNode->insertBefore($pseudostart, $ahref);
    $ahref->parentNode->insertBefore($ahref->cloneNode(true), $ahref); // Inserting cloned element (in order to insert $pseudoend immediately after)
    $ahref->parentNode->insertBefore($pseudoend, $ahref);
    $ahref->parentNode->removeChild($ahref); // Removing old element
}
print $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: Hiya, I'm looking to find each complete A tag <a href="xx">description</a> and then put $pseudostart before the <a and $pseudoend after the </a>

Comment: In that case you would probably want to add the "pseudo elements" as textNodes using `insertBefore()` and `appendChild()` (on the `ahref`'s parent).

Comment: can you elaborate on how to do that? The PHP manual documentation is less than clear to me.

Comment: OK updated the above completely to reflect the new situation - I really need to get this working, I can't see another way of doing it :)